# Typescript: typings.json is missing

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

Currently, I'm getting this compilation message:

> typings.json is missing

My current `packages.json` has this dependency:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    ...
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

the typescript compiler doesn't require 'typings.json' always, so you need to provide more info. Did you use npm to install 'typescript' already?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `npm` in order to install typescript. Moreover, it's also installed globally.

Comment: Remember the new way to do 'typings' in TypeScript is with NPM like this:

```
sudo npm install --save react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom
```
which is a react example of typings, but same thing "@typings" under node_modules is the current way the latest TypeScript wants typings. Other ways will probably fail.

Here is my project which uses TypeScript and the latest of everything including using typings:

https://github.com/Clay-Ferguson/meta64